# Is the IComparable interface outdated/"harmful"?

Tags: c#, sorting, comparison

### `IComparable` only works one way

Let's say you have a `Employee` class. In one view, you want to show all `Employees` sorted by name - in another, by address. How are you going to achieve that? Not with `IComparable`, at least not in any idiomatic way.

### `IComparable` has the logic in the wrong place

The interface is used by calling `.Sort()`. In a view showing `Customer` sorted by name, there is no code at all to implicate how it is going to be sorted.
On the other hand, the `Customer` class is assuming how it is going to be used - in this case, that it will be used in a list sorted by names.

### `IComparable` is used implicitly

In comparison with the alternatives, it is very difficult to see where the comparing logic is being used - or if at all. Assuming your standard IDE and starting from the `Customer` class, I will have to

1. Search for all references to `Customer`
2. Find those references which are used in a list
3. Check if those lists ever have `.Sort()` called on them

What's probably worse, if you remove an `IComparable` implementation that is still being used, you get no error or warning. The only thing you will get is wrong behaviour in all places that were too obscure for you to think of.

### These issues combined, plus changing requirements

The very reason I came to think about this is because it went wrong for me. I have been happily using `IComparable` in my application for 2 years now. Now, the requirements changed and the thing needs to be sorted in 2 different ways. It have noticed that it is no fun going through the steps described in the previous section.

### The question

These issues make me think of `IComparable` as inferior to `IComparer` or `.OrderBy()`, to the point of not seeing any valid use case that wouldn't be served better by the alternatives.
**Is it always better to use `IComparer` or LINQ, or are there advantages/use cases I am not seeing here?**

Comment: Your new "sort two different ways" requirement is a red herring.  To solve it, all you have to do is pass a different comparator to your sort function.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then you wouldn't be using `IComparable` anymore, which is reinforcing my point.

Comment: Don't forget that if you use the `SortedXXX` collections, they either require the stored elements to be `IComparable` or to have a `IComparer` provided.  Also note, that it is trivial to reverse the natural sort order with one comparer and have it work with all `IComparable` objects.

Comment: It doesn't matter that there are two different interfaces.  `IComparable` is considered the *default* comparison mechanism.  `IComparer` is used when you want to override the default comparison mechanism.

Comment: Example `ReverseComparer<T>`: https://gist.github.com/jackfarrington/078e7af7bc82482aa634

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, adding an IComparer isn't difficult or anything like that - my point is more that the first part also could already have been done with an IComparer and I wouldn't have needed a seperate interface (which provides the same functionality). Good point about the default though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IComparable` has the restrictions you mentioned, that is correct. It is an interface which was already available in .NET framework 1.0, where those functional alternatives and Linq were not available. So yes, one might see it as an outdated framework element which is mainly kept for backwards compatibility.

However, for lots of simple data structures, one way of sorting is probably enough or natural. For these cases, having one canonical place to implement the order relationship is still a good way to keep the code DRY, instead of always repeating the same logic in every call to `OrderBy` all over the place.

You have been "happily using IComparable in your application for 2 years now", as you wrote, so it appears to me it served you well for a long time. When you now have to validate, change and test all calls to `Sort`, it may also be a sign you were doing the same kind of sorting logic in many places, which is not the fault of `IComparable`. So this could be an occasion to centralize more of this logic in one place, making your code more DRY.

Comment: Good point about the simple data structures. However, the last paragraph doesn't make 100% sense to me. If I hadn't used `IComparable`, all the pre-existing sorting code would have been left untouched in their respective views, while I'd only add new sorting code for the new view.

Comment: @R.Schmitz Would the preexisting sort have worked correctly without the `IComparable` implementation that you wrote?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Of course, it's quite trivial to move that implementation to an `IComparer` or a LINQ `.OrderBy()`.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: Sure, but now you're committed to *always* providing a comparator (unless you use OrderBy, of course).  With `IComparable`, you get a default implementation for free, and sometimes you don't even have to write that implementation.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: when I got you right, noone is hindering you to let the `IComparable` interface as it is, and use `OrderBy` or a specific `IComparer` only at the places of the code where you need a different sort order. But see my edit.

Comment: I accepted this as answer because, in combination with comments by @RobertHarvey, it made me realize that `IComparable` is for a _default_ sorting order, which makes perfect sense for e.g. numerical types, while most of the objects I was thinking of don't _have_ a "natural" default sorting order.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: Your last comment there sums the point up nicely. I would go a little farther though. Suppose you have a numerical type like `BigInteger`. If it did not implement comparison operators/interfaces **how would you even implement an IComparer yourself**?  You'd need access to the internal data structures to do it efficiently, or at all. Suppose you have a type like Customer; the public properties you wish to sort on *do* have comparers.  For me that's the difference: implement `IComparable<T>` if it would be *unreasonable* to expect the caller to implement a comparer.

Comment: `If I hadn't used IComparable, all the pre-existing sorting code would have been left untouched in their respective views, while I'd only add new sorting code for the new view.` Just because `IComparable` was a _better_ solution _at the time_, doesn't mean it is the _best_ solution _today_. Your first comment here implies that "it's IComparable or nothing", which is not true, the problem could've been solved in many different ways. Applications can grow in size/scale, and things that used to look suitable may not be able to keep up with the application's increasing demands.

Comment: @Flater: if you want to address the OP, better use the "@" sign and his name, otherwise your comment looks like you are adressing me.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: Forgot to mention you in my comment above (2 places up from here)

Comment: @DocBrown: ...oops. Must've gotten lost.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your sentiments about `IComparable`

Just look at the remarks on `Array.Sort()`

- Each element of array must implement the `IComparable` interface to be capable of comparisons with every other element in array. *(or exception is thrown)*
- If the sort is not successfully completed, the results are undefined.

We will probably never now the motivation, However! consider `object.Equals()` a method on every object which lets you compare objects with each other to see if they are "the same"

You have that there already, but have been tasked with adding `Array.Sort()` you might want to add `object.Compare(object)`